# Problem syncdb-ing new BeautifulSoup package in django

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

This was the traceback, please help.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Documents and Settings\EC.32-SAMUEL\workspace\ec\ec\manage.py", line 11, in <module>
        execute_manager(settings)
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 219, in execute
        self.validate()
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 249, in validate
        num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 36, in get_validation_errors
        for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
        self._populate()
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 61, in _populate
        self.load_app(app_name, True)
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 83, in load_app
        if not module_has_submodule(app_module, 'models'):
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in module_has_submodule
        for entry in package.__path__:  # No __path__, then not a package.
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '
```

**path**'

Comment: What has this to do with BeautifulSoup???

Comment: i've installed other packages and there hasn't been any problem :s

Comment: please do help.. i've been stuck here.

Comment: there is zero indication for an issue with Beautifulsouü

Comment: hmmm, do i even need to syncdb beautiful soup or I can just import it into my views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is not a Django-app. Its a python package/module. You don't have to add to `INSTALLED_APPS`. It just need to be available in your PYTHONPATH to use it.

Your traceback doesn't give clue what is actually wrong with your Django project.

Comment: + no need to say sorry. We all started like this. :P

Answer (score 0):

The only time you ever need to do a syncdb is when you have to do something to the db. BeautifulSoup does not need to use the db at any point and does not need to be an installed app